# Azure Event Subject Filtering For Specific Blob Storage

Tags: azure, filter, azure-eventgrid

in the [Documentation linked here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-filtering#subject-filtering)

The following is stated regarding filtering:
"For simple filtering by subject, specify a starting or ending value for the subject. For example, you can specify the subject ends with .txt to only get events related to uploading a text file to storage account. Or, you can filter the subject begins with /blobServices/default/containers/testcontainer to get all events for that container but not other containers in the storage account."

I am a bit confused by the example,

can someone please explain what each part of this address is?

is the whole thing required to target only a specific container on a specific StorageAccount?

for example, to target only container "ContainerName" in blob storage "BlobStorageName" do i use "/blobServices/blobStorageName/containers/containerName" etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/blobServices/default/containers/"container-name"/blobs/"file-name"

found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema